# Call SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand in an EventTrigger (xaml)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ResourceDictionary. A button is defined in this dictionary. This button has the command SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand. Here is my simplified code.

It works:

```
<Button x:Name="PART_ButtonMinimize"
    Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}" />
```

However I want to call several commands with this button. The commands should be called in the xaml file and not via a DependencyProperty.
That's why I changed the xaml code like this (here only with one command in a ResourceDictionary):

```
<Button x:Name="PART_ButtonMinimize">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But this does not work. The command SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand is not called.
Above it works and in the EventTrigger no reaction.
If I call a DependencyProperty command with InvokeCommandAction then it works.
So the call of SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand must be the cause.
Does anyone know why? What do I have to change?

Thanks.

Comment: This does work assuming you have actually set up a `CommandBinding` for the `MinimizeWindowCommand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InvokeCommandAction` does not know how to invoke a `RoutedCommand`. It only calls `ICommand.Execute` which is not enough in order to execute it.
I assume this feature was not implemented as it would be totally redundant. This is because routed commands are essentially routed events. And it absolutely makes no sense to convert a routed event to a routed command (another routed event).

Using Interaction behaviors is rarely a good solution. It only leads to odd design decisions. WPF provides all the necessary and powerful features. There is nothing wrong with handling boring events the ordinary way. Events are fine and don't violate any design patterns. Why bother with additional code to convert events to commands?

You have to implement the routed command handlers. Also don't bind to the static read-only `RoutedCommand` property. Simply assign the static `RoutedCommand` value to the `Button.Command` property.

The static `SystemCommands` class defines both the routed command e.g. `SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand` and the associated static handler method `SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(Window)`.
`SystemCommands` also provides helpers for each of its commands: `CloseWindow()`, `MaximizeWindow()`, `MinimizeWindow()`, `RestoreWindow()`, `ShowSystemMenu()`):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}"
                    Executed="ExecuteMinimizeWindowCommand"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteWindowCommands" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Button Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private void CanExecuteWindowCommands(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = true;

  private void ExecuteMinimizeWindowCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
}
```

Another solution is to handle the `Button.Click` event and execute all required operations from the event handler.

Comment: Thanks. But it should work with <i:Interaction.Triggers>. Just as I described above. The <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"> should then trigger several DependencyProperty commands. DependencyProperty commands work. Only the SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand does not work with <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">. However, it must be implemented there in order to obtain a specific sequence of commands.

Comment: The key information I was trying to get over was that you have to implement the behavior of the command and handle it. This is a routed command. My example is showing how to handle a routed command.  It also shows how to correctly reference a routed command (do not use Binding here!).

Comment: However, this is not a scenario for an interaction trigger. It's completely redundant here because it doesn't make sense to let the trigger handle a routed event only to raise another one (the routed command). As you can see from my example you have to handle it on an ancestor element. I assume that this fact is the reason that they chose not to implement a redundant feature like executing routed events for dependency objects.

Comment: Long story short: the interaction trigger is not able to execute routed commands. By the way, why are you using EventTrigger at all? You can handle the Click event and execute the commands from the event handler. This would also reduce the markup code. I think my answer solves your problem. In the event handler you have full control over the oder of the sequence of invoked operations.

Comment: Interaction triggers are pretty much redundant helpers, especially when used with any ICommandSource like a Button. It just overcomplicates a trivial problem. They also let people make bad design decisions and implement anti patterns because they found a way to delegate UI logic to the view model (in MVVM applications). Instead of interaction triggers I recommend using the existing and powerful features of the framework and .NET library.